# "I do" in the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence "I love my veg I do" what is the purpose of the "I do" part?
It seems to me that it gives a sprinkle of assertiveness, but a definite explanation would really help.

Comment: You're right. It's a restatement for emphasis (which is one of _do_'s roles - compare 'I _do_ like spinach' with 'I like spinach'). Your example (which needs a comma) is in a pretty informal, almost rustic or childish, register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is spot on, especially on his point about register — when I read your sentence, that trailing "I do" gives it a definite West Country or Norfolk twang.

Comment: @ 568ml Whoops. Going there (Norfolk) for hols. For 'childish' read 'quaint regional'.

Comment: Yes, I took it as it is, without changing it, from a BBC tv show. BTW, what's wrong with the register?

Comment: For I like a drop of good beer, I do, / I'm fond of a drop of good beer, I is, / Let the gentlemen fine sit down to their wine, / But I will stick to my beer.  Somerset drinking song.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would you, please, format you comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: "I do" is the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're right. It's a restatement for emphasis (which is one of *do*'s roles - compare 'I *do* like spinach' with 'I like spinach'). Your example (which needs a comma) is in a pretty informal, almost rustic or childish, register.

Edwin Ashworth